# Google Calendar: "tentative" status is not available as an option?

Tags: google-api, google-calendar-api

Using Google for Work, for a primary calendar, for an event without invitees.

I don't see *tentative* as an option for events. I only see:

```
Show me as: ( ) Available  (x) Busy 
Visibility: (x) Calendar default  ( ) Public  ( ) Private
```

In the [Calendar API (v3)](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events?hl=en) it says the status for an event can be: *confirmed / tentative / cancelled*.

I can indeed write/read that status using the API.
Setting it to *tentative* using the API does not change how the event is displayed in either the Google Calendar web interface, Google Calendar app, or e.g. iOS Calendar app.

How can I use/see/change the *tentative* status (for events without invitees) using the clients?

Comment: I dont think you can create a message as tentative.  But if you/invitee accepts invitation as "may be" then this event status become tentative. Also, tentative is the invitee response status to the event. You cannot get this status for the events without invitees. check this link https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events . Let me know if your scenario is different.

Comment: The link you shared is the same as mine. ;-) In there you see two cases for tentative: status = status of the event (incl. "tentative") and attendees[].responseStatus = the attendee's response status (incl. "tentative"). This suggests it is possible to set a status to an event without attendees.

Comment: Event status tentative has no special representation in calendar UIs AFAIK

Answer (score 1):

Based on (removed source article as it died) I think you need the following trick to achieve what you are looking for:

Rather than having a calendar item without attendees, add yourself as an attendee

This should allow you to put something in the calendar as tentative. Possibly you need to update the status after creation.

Comment: The article seems to point to droneup.com -- has the link become outdated?

Comment: @JoelLee The link is indeed dead so I removed it but I can confirm that the solution as described in my answer still work, I use it now and then.

Comment: Ah that's a shame, was looking forward to reading the article. Thanks for the swift response